# Kivy notification bar

Tags: android, kivy

I want to create a notification in the notification bar on android, but i did not find a solution. Is there a way to do it with pyjnius?

The Android Module does not work because in kivy it's not the same as in PY4A where it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) has a notification function. Does this do what you want?

You can also do it by calling the android api directly with pyjnius.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I was searching for thos a very long time and i also searched in the plyer documentation but didn't find anything. But it is so simple. Thank you and good luck with your apps ;)

Comment: @inclement Plyer notification is working well on Windows but, when I compile my to APK and run it on android, it gives me this error in the logcat. `'org.test.myapp.R$drawable' has no attribute 'icon'`. So is there any way to solve this. Thanks in advance